# Nonatomatic assign and memory leak issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I have one property say

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) NSString *str;
```

Now I am having something like

```
self.str = [[NSString alloc] init];
self.str = @"test";
NSLog(@"%@",str);
[self.str release];
```

When I run I can see a leak "Potential leak of memory".

Why its showing me leak ?

Please guide me I am leaning phase of iOS

Comment: If you're in the "learning phase" you should probably skip manual reference counting and go straight to ARC.

Comment: @HotLicks - I usually give the opposite advice: use arc after you know what's really going on.

Comment: And even if this were ARC his first line would still be a serious mistake (a misunderstanding of how things get instantiated, initialized, etc.).

Comment: @HotLicks I thought to go with MRC to understand memory management.

Comment: We are agreeing with that (some of us). But first you also need to understand how instantiation and assignment work! :)

Comment: @danh - If the user seems to have a basic understanding of things, such that he will get beyond the intro course, starting with manual RC is probably best.  But that's not obviously the case here.

Comment: Probably not relevant to your problem here, but FYI, it's a bad idea to write code like `self.something = @"Some NSString"; [self.something release];`. Depending on the accessors for the `something` property, the object returned by the getter may not be the same exact one that was used in the setter, so you may end up leaking one object and overreleasing another. It's better to use a local variable to hold the object you're assigning to the property and release it through that reference. So: `NSString *localString = @"Some NSString"; self.something = localString; [localString release];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use factory method or create object using **alloc,new,retain,copy,mutableCopy** your object has **+1 retain** count every time. You own object in this case. You are responsible for releasing it. So you need to **release** object after you finish using object which cause **-1 retain count** to object.

It is not necessary to alloc you string again as you are already creating its property.

And it has its getter setter + you are allocating it again so gives you a leak.

Comment: thanks buddy can you tell me refrence for retain counts. Are retainCounts reliable ?

Comment: retain counts are not reliable. as per documentation

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html look at this .Also retain count are not reliable as Anoop said.

Comment: @Anoop 1)he should not over alloc str object. 2) He need to release in dealloc method or any where if not going to be used in future.

Answer (score 5):

In other words (I'm just expanding on Anoop's answer here), you have two strings, not one.

```
self.str = [[NSString alloc] init];
self.str = @"test";
```

The thing on the right side of the first line is a string: `[[NSString alloc] init]`. But in the second line you throw it away, replacing it with a *different* string, namely `@"test"`. Now there is NO REFERENCE pointing to the first string. Thus it leaks, since it can never be released nor can anything else ever be done to or for it.

The situation of the string created in the first line is, after the second line, like the situation of "thing1" in the second panel of this diagram:

[image]

No one is pointing to it, so its memory cannot be managed, and it lives forever in isolation (leak).

Comment: And there's more where that came from!

Comment: What an instance reference is: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch03.html#_an_instance_reference_is_a_pointer

Comment: We'll just call you Dr. Seuss.

Comment: @matt thanks but i cnt vote up because of my rep :(. But thaks for explanation

Comment: @user2270800 No problem! I just hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
self.str = [[NSString alloc] init]; //1st
```

One string is allocated not used.

```
self.str = @"test";  // 2nd
```

Another constant string "test" is allocated but released.

So first one is a leak.

Comment: Yep, the OP fell afoul of the common Objective-C novice misconception that you must "allocate" a pointer before you assign to it.  Occurs almost as often as the misconception that simply declaring an object pointer is sufficient to create it.

Comment: I am releasing object using [self.str release];

Comment: @user2270800: actually you released  2nd one. what about first one?

Comment: @user2270800 - You released the *second* object -- `@"test"` -- but not the first one.

Comment: @HotLicks: at the time you started typing i added new comment similar to u.

Comment: So should i write release twise ?

Comment: @user2270800 - DON'T DO THE USELESS `[[NSString alloc] init]`.

Comment: ***No** you can create 1st one in auto-released way, [nsstring string] or [[[nsstring alloc]init]autorelease]. But why to create an empty one?

Comment: @user2270800 - And while we're at it, never do `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", someString]`

Comment: this statement is same as `someString` directly putting to string object.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya - Correct, yet it's amazing how often you see it here.

Comment: @HotLicks @AnoopVaidya: Those are not necessarily equivalent. Consider the case where `someString` is actually mutable. (Though `[NSString stringWithString:someString]` is a more sensible way to get a non-owning reference to a guaranteed-immutable version of an arbitrary string.)

Comment: @Chuck - I never said you might not need something else.  Just that there's never a place where you should use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", someString]`.

Comment: @HotLicks: Anoop said it's "the same as `someString`" — I was clarifying that this is not strictly accurate, as there is an important semantic difference.

Comment: @Chuck - There are a lot of important semantic differences that got glossed over in this thread.